# Google Analytics: Post transaction iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, google-analytics-api

I want to send some information about my application via Google analytics for iOS. When I'm sending regular events they are successfully coming to the server. But Ecommerce unfortunately won't. Despite the fact that I did it strictly to Google API
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/ecommerce?hl=sk

Here is the way that I'm doing this:

```
GAITransaction *transaction =
[GAITransaction transactionWithId:orderId            // (NSString) Transaction ID, should be unique.
                  withAffiliation:@"appname"];       // (NSString) Affiliation
transaction.taxMicros = (int64_t)(0 * 1000000);           // (int64_t) Total tax (in micros)
transaction.shippingMicros = (int64_t)(0);                   // (int64_t) Total shipping (in micros)
transaction.revenueMicros = (int64_t)(**price** * 1000000);

[transaction addItemWithCode:@"orderIos"
                        name:@"orderIos"
                    category:@"orderIos"
                 priceMicros:(int64_t)(self._price * 1000000)
                    quantity:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] ];
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker sendTransaction:transaction];
```

Why this code doesn't work?

---

**Resolved**
it works but you should sett revenue in micros as price * quantity. without this field analytics thinks that you transaction is 0

Comment: Have you run through the code and checked if the object 'transaction' has all the correct values and expected data types? Try enabling debug mode. Will help you with finding what the problem is.

Comment: Yes I've already checked all values they are correct. Debug mode did not help too